# Embedding of punctured torus with euclidean metric

Tags: riemannian-geometry

A flat two-torus, $T^2$ that is the torus with Euclidean metric needs to be embedded at least  in $\mathbb{R}^4$. If we puncture the torus and leave the Euclidean metric on it as inherited (ignoring the issues of completeness), what ambient space could you embed the punctured torus with Euclidean metric?

Comment: It is a bit strange to call the flat metric on the torus the *Euclidean metric*...

Comment: Thinking of $T^2$ as $\mathbb R^2/\mathbb Z^2$, the term Euclidean metric makes some sense. :)